# Solid mechanics: Deflection of a rectangular elastic membrane

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, beam, deformation

I am trying to solve for the deflection $w$ of a rectangular membrane with tension $T$ acting on two opposite edges. These two edges are fixed i.e. $w = 0$. The other two opposite edges are free. The size of the membrane is $L$x$L$. There is a pressure $P$ acting on an area $\frac{L}{3}$x$\frac{L}{3}$ at the centre of the membrane.

A schematic is presented below:

[image]

If the tension was acting on four edges and they were fixed. The equations and boundary conditions could be written as: 
$$T\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial x^2}+T\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2} = p$$
with boundary conditions:
$$w(x=0) = w(x=L) = w(y=0) = w(y=L) = 0$$

I do not know how to modify these equations and boundary conditions for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

This answer expands upon the approach suggested by @setun-90 and shows that the algebra gets quite complicated.  I'd suggest a Green's function approach instead.

**Assumptions**

- isotropic
- deflection of membrane is small
- applied tension large so that its variation due to deflection is small

**Governing equation**

Let the tension in the $x, y$-directions be $T_x, T_y$ per unit length, respectively.
Let $w$ be the lateral deflection.
The resultant in the $w$-direction due to the tension $T_x$ on the $dy$-edge of a 
small element of area $(dx \times dy)$ is
$$
  R_x := (T_x dy) \left(\theta_x + \frac{\partial \theta_x}{\partial x}\, dx\right) - 
  (T_x dy)\, \theta_x = T_x\, \frac{\partial \theta_x}{\partial x}\, dx dy
$$
where we have used $\sin\theta_x \approx \theta_x$ for small $\theta_x$ and
$
  \theta_x := \frac{\partial w}{\partial x} \,.
$
Similarly, the resultant in the $w$-direction due to $T_y$ is
$$
  R_y := (T_y dx) \left(\theta_y + \frac{\partial \theta_y}{\partial y}\, dy\right) - 
  (T_y dx)\, \theta_y = T_y\, \frac{\partial \theta_y}{\partial y}\, dx dy
$$
where 
$
  \theta_y := \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} \,.
$
Therefore, the total lateral force due to $T_x$ and $T_y$ is
$$
  R = R_x + R_y = \left(T_x\, \frac{\partial \theta_x}{\partial x} +
                        T_y\, \frac{\partial \theta_y}{\partial y}\right) dx dy \,.
$$
This force is balanced by the applied lateral pressure, $p(x,y)$, and we have
$$
   p(x, y)\, dx dy + \left(T_x\, \frac{\partial \theta_x}{\partial x} +
                        T_y\, \frac{\partial \theta_y}{\partial y}\right) dx dy = 0 \,.
$$
Plugging in the definitions of $\theta_x$ and $\theta_y$, and eliminating $dx dy$, we get the governing equation
get
$$ \boxed{
   p(x, y) + T_x\, \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2} +
                        T_y\, \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} = 0 \,.}
$$

**Case where $T_x = T$ and $T_y = 0$**

In this case, the governing equation reduces to
$$
  \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}  = -\frac{p(x,y)}{T} \,.
$$
Integrating once, we have
$$
  \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}  = -\int\frac{p(x,y)}{T}\,dx + F(y) + F_c
$$
where $F(y)$ is an integration function and $F_c$ is an integration constant.
Integrating again
$$\boxed{
   w(x, y) = \int\left[-\int\frac{p(x,y)}{T}\,dx + F(y) + F_c\right] dx + G(y) + G_c }
$$
where $G(y)$ is another integration function and $G_c$ is an integration constant.

**Case where $p(x,y)$ is a discontinuous function**

Consider the case where
$$
  p(x,y) = \begin{cases}
              0 & \text{for} \quad 0 \le x < \tfrac{L}{3}, 0 \le y \le L \\
              0 & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    0 \le y < \tfrac{L}{3} \\
              P & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3} ,
                    \tfrac{L}{3} \le y \le \tfrac{2L}{3}\\
              0 & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    \tfrac{2L}{3} < y \le L \\
              0 & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{2L}{3} < x \le L, 0 \le y \le L 
           \end{cases}
$$
Then, 
$$
   \int \frac{p(x,y)}{T}\,dx = \begin{cases}
              0 & \text{for} \quad 0 \le x < \tfrac{L}{3}, 0 \le y \le L \\
              0 & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    0 \le y < \tfrac{L}{3} \\
              \tfrac{Px}{T} & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    \tfrac{L}{3} \le y \le \tfrac{2L}{3}\\
              0 & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    \tfrac{2L}{3} < y \le L \\
              0 & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{2L}{3} < x \le L , 0 \le y \le L 
           \end{cases}
$$
This leads to
$$
  \frac{\partial w}{\partial x}  = \begin{cases}
              F_1(y) + F_{c1} & \text{for} \quad 0 \le x < \tfrac{L}{3}, 0 \le y \le L \\
              F_2(y) + F_{c2} & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    0 \le y < \tfrac{L}{3} \\
              -\tfrac{Px}{T} + F_3(y) + F_{c3} & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    \tfrac{L}{3} \le y \le \tfrac{2L}{3}\\
              F_4(y) + F_{c4} & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    \tfrac{2L}{3} < y \le L \\
              F_5(y) + F_{c5} & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{2L}{3} < x \le L , 0 \le y \le L 
           \end{cases}
$$
From the second integration:
$$\boxed{
  w(x,y)  = \begin{cases}
              [F_1(y) + F_{c1}]\,x + G_1(y) + G_{1c} & \text{for} \quad 0 \le x < \tfrac{L}{3}, 0 \le y \le L \\
              [F_2(y) + F_{c2}]\,x + G_2(y) + G_{2c}& \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    0 \le y < \tfrac{L}{3} \\
              -\frac{Px^2}{2T} + [F_3(y) + F_{c3}]\,x + G_3(y) + G_{3c} & \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    \tfrac{L}{3} \le y \le \tfrac{2L}{3}\\
              [F_4(y) + F_{c4}]\,x + G_4(y) + G_{4c}& \text{for} \quad \tfrac{L}{3} \le x \le \tfrac{2L}{3},
                    \tfrac{2L}{3} < y \le L \\
              [F_5(y) + F_{c5}]\,x + G_5(y) + G_{5c}& \text{for} \quad \tfrac{2L}{3} < x \le L , 0 \le y \le L 
           \end{cases}}
$$
The 20 unknown quantities in this solution need 20 boundary conditions, making the algebra quite complex.

**Green's function approach**

An alternative is to use the Green's function approach in which we start with an assumed sinusoidal lateral load
$$
  p(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_0 \sin \frac{m\pi x}{a} \sin \frac{n\pi y}{b}
$$
where $a$ and $b$ are the dimensions of the membrane.  We can then specialize the solution to the case where the applied load is a point load at the location $(\xi,\eta)$.  Let $K(x,y,\xi,\eta)$ be this solution for a point load.  Then the total deflection can be computed using
$$
  w(x,y) = \iint_A p(\chi,\eta) K(x, y, \chi, \eta) \,d\chi d\eta \,.
$$
Details of this approach can be found in Section 29 of "Theory of Plates and Shells" by Timoshenko and Woinowsky-Krieger.

Comment: I think you still need to split the domain into two regions (with $P$ and without) when using Green's function.

Comment: @ja72:  That's correct.  The $(\xi,\eta)$ coordinates determine that region.  However, the complicated matching of boundary conditions at the edges and corners can be avoided because you are just integrating over a square.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of a solution:
$w$ can be considered a function only of $x$ since two sides are bound. Therefore ${\partial w\over\partial y}=0$ therefore
 ${\partial^2w\over\partial y^2}=0$.

Then you have three regions ($[0;{L\over3}],[{L\over3};{2L\over3}],[{2L\over3};L]$, called $R_1$,$R_2$ and $R_3$):

- $x\in R_1\implies P=0 \\
  \implies {\partial^2w_1\over\partial x^2}(x)=0\implies{\partial w_1\over\partial x}(x)=A_1\\ \implies w_1(x)=A_1x+B_1$
- $x\in R_2\implies P\ne 0 \\
  \implies {\partial^2w_2\over\partial x^2}(x)={P\over T}\implies{\partial w_2\over\partial x}(x)={P\over T}x+B_2\\ \implies w_2(x)={P\over2T}x^2+B_2x+C$
- $x\in R_3\implies P=0 \\
  \implies {\partial^2w_3\over\partial x^2}(x)=0\implies{\partial w_3\over\partial x}(x)=A_3\\ \implies w_3(x)=A_3x+B_3$

Finally, you need to join the functions together (continuity, derivatives and function itself), which will take an enormous amount of time in this case (you're basically dealing with a spline here).

Comment: I wasn't sure about $$\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2} = 0$$ but I think you are right. Other than that since _P_ is only applied in a fraction of the membrane, we need to break down the problem into two parts: one where _P_ is non zero and other where it is zero. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes I know about the split region. I'm working on it, but it's taking a long time (continuity & boundary conditions). But the method for this problem basically starts with noting dw/dy = 0.

Comment: I don't think $\dfrac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2}=0$ is valid in this case since the load isn't applied along all of $y$. The deflection at $x=0, y=\dfrac{L}{2}$ will be different than that at $x=y=\dfrac{L}{2}$.

Comment: ...I'm sorry, I failed to understand your illustration. Did you mean $x={L\over2},y=0$ or $x=y=0$ (since we are talking about y direction)? In any case, I unfortunately can only offer this solution, as multivariable differential equations escape my knowledge (strangely, we haven't yet seen any examples in second year).

Comment: @Wasabi 

Do you think $$\frac{\partial^2w}{\partial y^2} = 0$$ is valid for region where pressure is not acting?